# TS: Construct type from optional properties of interface

Tags: typescript

Supposing we have a similar interface:

```js
interface Interface {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz?: boolean;
}
```

How can we construct a type with only its optional properties?

With the interface above, I'd be looking to something like:

```js
interface PartialInterface {
  baz: boolean;
}
```

A solution would be of course to use either `Omit` or `Pick`; That would work on small interfaces, but it wouldn't really be suitable for bigger scenarios.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger scenarios"?

Comment: Bigger interfaces or types. I'd want to avoid writing a long list of properties to either pick or omit, especially because that will also require to be updated every time the main interface gets its properties updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll combine the [removal of the `?` modifier using the `-` prefix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) and [filtering properties with the `as` keyword](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) in mapped types:

```js
type PickOptionals<T> = {
    // `Interface` below extends
    // + `Record<"foo", string>` and
    // + `Record<"bar", number>` but not
    // - `Record<"baz", boolean>`.
    // Since the right side of `as` evaluates to `never` when
    // `K` is "foo" or "bar", those properties are dropped entirely.
    [K in keyof T as T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K]-?: T[K];
}

interface Interface {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz?: boolean;
}

type PartialInterface = PickOptionals<Interface>
// = { baz: boolean }
```

[Here's a playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) for good measure

Comment: Thanks for the input, although not sure that's quite the behaviour - It returns `type PartialInterface = { foo?: undefined; bar?: undefined; baz?: boolean | undefined; }`

Comment: @ale917k [I cannot reproduce that behaviour](https://tsplay.dev/m3y6qw). Can you link a playground with your TSC settings where I could take a look?

Comment: @ale917k You might've forgotten the `-` before `?` when copying `PickOptionals<T>` — at least that'd seem to be consistent with your result. The `-` is [required to mark properties as non-optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers).

Comment: Yes apology, I was going to say that's my bad for missing the dash - well caught! I quite like the solution as that's clever, but do you perhaps know if we can avoid inserting the property instead of setting it to never, when not optional? The only thing bugging me, is that intellisense suggests those properties too

Comment: @EmmaKoskinen you could use key remapping to suppress keys, essentially move your conditional type inside the `[K in keyof T]` section like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLl2Vm).  I won't write up my own answer if you [edit] yours to something like this.

Comment: @jcalz Yup, I was about to write almost exactly that  Just a second, I'll write an explanation for it while I'm at it.